# setting a property of function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

Whenever I write

[image: console]

I can't seem to find the `prop` property , when I try to view `func` in console.

Where does the `prop` property go and How does the property setting work?

Comment: I know I can access it using `func.prop`.But where is it set?

Comment: it is set in the properties of your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop` is being defined on the `func` function reference.

To access the property  use `func.prop` or do `console.dir(func)` will show the property in the property tree

Comment: do `console.dir(func)` in console , u'll find the property

Answer (score 0):

IMO the following is is more intuitive than `console.dir`:

1. Open Firefox instead of Chrome
2. Run that code in Firefox's web console
3. Click the returned function
4. The object inspect subpanel will show the properties.

[image]